# If $(X \times Y, \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}, \mu \times \nu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, does that imply $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm having trouble proving or disproving the statement:

> If the product space $(X \times Y, \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}, \mu \times \nu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, then so is $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$.

I don't think this is true.  My idea is that if $X \times Y = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_{n}$ with $(\mu \times \nu)(E_{n}) < \infty$, we can't necessarily write $E_{n} = A_{n} \times B_{n}$ for $A_{n} \in \Sigma$ and $B_{n} \in \tau$.  I don't know where to go from there, assuming the statement is false.

> **Update**
>
> Is this a suitable counterexample?
>
> Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu) = (\{0, 1\}, \mu = m \text{ (Lebesgue measure)}, \mathcal{P}(X))$, and $(Y, \tau, \nu) = (\mathbb{R}, \Sigma(m^{*}), m)$.  Then the measure $\mu \times \nu$ is $\sigma$-finite assuming $m$.  Is anything wrong with this?

Comment: Hint: What if $\nu$ is the zero measure?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the hint.  I thought of something similar, and I am wondering if it is right.  I updated my question with my idea.  Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @NateEldredge I think the only way it would be wrong is if the Lebesgue measure is not a measure on the power set of $\{0, 1 \}$.  How would I check that?  My guess is that it is a measure on the power set because the power set is a subset of $\Sigma(m^{*})$, the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: I guess it *would* be a measure on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ since the power set is itself a $\sigma$-algebra, so it is trivial to prove that if $m$ is a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$, and $\mathcal{P}(X) \subseteq \Sigma$ for some set $X$, since power set is also a $\sigma$-algebra, and a subset of $\Sigma$, then $m$ is a measure on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, too....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nate's hint suggested, we can take $$(X, \Sigma, \mu) = (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), 0 \text{ (the zero measure)})$$ and $$(Y, \tau, \nu) = (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), \mu \text{ (counting measure)})$$ and writing $X \times Y$ as the countable union $\bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} X \times Y_{n}$ (with $Y = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} Y_{n}$).  The measure of each set in the union is finite since $0 \cdot \infty = 0$.  But $(Y,\tau,\nu)$ is not $\sigma$-finite since $Y$ is uncountable and $\nu$ is counting measure.